# Angular groupby and merge array

Tags: angular, toarray, mergemap

￼1

I am trying to merge duplicate value objects in an array but not working...
[I have my result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lO2W.png)

[but I want my data like this help me pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYyJD.png)

this is my code

-

```
     dataa = [
           {
             date: '07/05/2020 00:09',
             id: '5920501995',
             score: 0,
             student: 'boon boon',
           },
          ....] 
source = from(this.dataa);
//group by age
 example = this.source.pipe(
  groupBy(person => person.id),
  // return each item in group as array
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())));
 subscribe = this.example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
 -
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of logging, you can push to another variable

```
const values= [];
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => {
values.push(val);
});
```